# Understand constructor property in javascript

Tags: javascript

Seems I didn't understand the `constructor` concept, So, I wrote some code to test it. Say you have the code like this:

```
var test=function(){...}
```

I know there is a property named `constructor` in the `test.prototype` object which point to the `test` object.

Here comes my question:

Is this property(`constructor`) only belongs to the prototype object ? or Do all the objects have the `constructor` property?

And I did another test. the code like below:

```
            function Shape() {
              this.x = 0;
              this.y = 0;
            }

            Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
                this.x += x;
                this.y += y;
                console.info("Shape moved.");
            };

            Rectangle = Object.create(Shape);//inherit from the Shape instead of Shape.prototype
            Rectangle.constructor==Function//it is true.
```

I don't know where does `Rectangle.constuctor` come from or does it inherit from the `Shape`? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.create` returns an object whose prototype is the object you pass it.

Therefore, since `Shape.constructor` is `Function` (`Shape` is a `Function` object), `Rectangle` inherits that.

Comment: Do all the objects have the `constructor` property?

Comment: Do you mean only `Function` object like `Shape` has the `constructor`? thanks.

Comment: I think it exactly comes from `Function.prototype`, Not as your said from the `Shape` ,because the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) says `All objects inherit a constructor property from their prototype`, Am I right ?

Comment: @Joe.wang, You may have some confusion about prototypes.  Read this article: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/